# How long does it take for "service mysql start" to start mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, terminal

I ran a service mysql stop and followed it with a service mysql start, however, this process has been going for about 2 hours now and I don't know if it's a bad idea to kill the process. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: This should take about 5-10 seconds.

Comment: kill kill no prob , and start again

Comment: Normally it should not take more than 3-4 seconds.
But if it is taking more time then you should inspect what exactly is happening by mysqld command

Answer (score 3):

I had to write answer cause I do not have enough reputation to make a comment.

I was dealing with the same problem. MySQL version 5.7.9. I was working on some configuration settings and I realized that some configurations somehow preventing MySQL server start. It just keeps trying to start server giving no error. 
These are the config that I was trying to configure from the URL https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/41873:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=4G
innodb_buffer_pool_instance=2
innodb_read_io_threads=12
innodb_write_io_threads=12
innodb_io_capacity=300
innodb_log_file_size=128M
```

Disclaimer:  I wrote that answer just because I think It may useful for someone but also I am angry at the OP. He/she probably solved the problem somehow (reinstall also is an answer) but did not write it down.

Comment: Don't be angry, they probably just killed the process and retried.  "Never attribute to malice that which is adequately explained by stupidity".

Comment: @PeteGO good reminder I also see no process on mysqld. There was no process to kill. Anyway, I hope this helps someone. Btw, I am still trying to understand that wise words as non-native English speaker.